# Gradle: Could not get unknown property

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew, bitbucket-pipelines

Already defined the repository variables needed.

[image]

This is the Gradle wrapper command in the pipeline

```
- step:
        name: Create Keystores and Google Play API key file
        script:
          - mkdir keys # create new directory
          - echo $DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE_BASE64 | base64 -d > keys/$DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE # decode base64 then use DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE as file name defined in repository variable
          - echo $KEYSTORE_FILE_BASE64 | base64 -d > keys/$KEYSTORE_FILE # decode base64 then use KEYSTORE_FILE as file name defined in repository variable
          - echo $GOOGLE_PLAY_API_KEY_BASE64 | base64 -d > keys/$GOOGLE_PLAY_API_KEY_FILE # decode base64 then use GOOGLE_PLAY_API_KEY_FILE as file name defined in repository variable
        artifacts:
          - keys/** # keep these artifacts for subsequent pipeline steps

- step:
        name: Build & Deploy (Internal)
        caches: # caching speed up subsequent execution https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-dependencies/
          - gradle
        script:
          # publish the aab file to the internal testing channel
          # the plugin publishes to the internal testing track by default
          - chmod +x gradlew
          - "./gradlew
                       -PANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION
                       -PANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION
                       -PANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION

                       -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE=../keys/$DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE
                       -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$DEBUG_PASSWORD
                       -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS=$DEBUG_KEY_ALIAS
                       -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASSWORD=$DEBUG_KEY_PASSWORD

                       -PAPPNAME_KEYSTORE_FILE=../keys/$KEYSTORE_FILE
                       -PAPPNAME_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
                       -PAPPNAME_KEY_ALIAS=$KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS
                       -PAPPNAME_KEY_PASSWORD=$KEY_PASSWORD

                       -PGOOGLE_PLAY_API_KEY=../keys/$GOOGLE_PLAY_API_KEY

                       -PBUILD_NUMBER=$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER

                        clean :app:publishReleaseBundle"
        artifacts:
          - app/build/outputs/ # artifacts are files that are produced by a step https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/
```

The problem is
`-PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE=../keys/$DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE` is somewhat being ignored and not working during build.

```
Build setup5s

chmod +x gradlew<1s

./gradlew -PANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION -PANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION -PANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE=../keys/$DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$DEBUG_PASSWORD -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS=$DEBUG_KEY_ALIAS -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASSWORD=$DEBUG_KEY_PASSWORD -PAPPNAME_KEYSTORE_FILE=../keys/$KEYSTORE_FILE -PAPPNAME_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -PAPPNAME_KEY_ALIAS=$KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS -PAPPNAME_KEY_PASSWORD=$KEY_PASSWORD -PGOOGLE_PLAY_API_KEY=../keys/$GOOGLE_PLAY_API_KEY -PBUILD_NUMBER=$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER clean :app:publishFreeReleaseBundle39s

+ ./gradlew -PANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION -PANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION -PANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
-PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE=../keys/$DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$DEBUG_PASSWORD -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS=$DEBUG_KEY_ALIAS -PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASSWORD=$DEBUG_KEY_PASSWORD
-PAPPNAME_KEYSTORE_FILE=../keys/$KEYSTORE_FILE -PAPPNAME_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -PAPPNAME_KEY_ALIAS=$KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS -PAPPNAME_KEY_PASSWORD=$KEY_PASSWORD
-PGOOGLE_PLAY_API_KEY=../keys/$GOOGLE_PLAY_API_KEY
-PBUILD_NUMBER=$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
clean :app:publishFreeReleaseBundle
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-bin.zip
...........................................................................................................
Unzipping /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0-bin/2p9ebqfz6ilrfozi676ogco7n/gradle-7.0-bin.zip to /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0-bin/2p9ebqfz6ilrfozi676ogco7n
Set executable permissions for: /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0-bin/2p9ebqfz6ilrfozi676ogco7n/gradle-7.0/bin/gradle
Welcome to Gradle 7.0!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - File system watching enabled by default
 - Support for running with and building Java 16 projects
 - Native support for Apple Silicon processors
 - Dependency catalog feature preview
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/release-notes.html
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/app/build.gradle' line: 27
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE' for SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug, storeFile=/opt/android-sdk-linux/.android/debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=pkcs12, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true, enableV1Signing=null, enableV2Signing=null, enableV3Signing=null, enableV4Signing=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 39s
```

However trying to test it out further I tried to remove `-PANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION` argument and the error is now on compileSdk

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/app/build.gradle' line: 13
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 39s
```

With this I assumed that the argument works fine but when it comes to signing it seems that my own signing config is being ignored.

This is the app Gradle file looks like.

```
android {
    compileSdk Integer.parseInt(ANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION)

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.name"
        minSdk Integer.parseInt(ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdk Integer.parseInt(ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode project.hasProperty('BUILD_NUMBER') ? project['BUILD_NUMBER'].toInteger() : 14
        versionName "1.3.3"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file(DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE)
            storePassword DEBUG_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias DEBUG_KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword DEBUG_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
        release {
            storeFile file(APPNAME_KEYSTORE_FILE)
            storePassword APPNAME_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias APPNAME_KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword APPNAME_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable "MissingClass"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

play {
    serviceAccountCredentials.set(file(GOOGLE_PLAY_API_KEY_FILE))
}
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems like its not specific to debug signing but also with release I get
`Could not get unknown property 'APPNAME_KEYSTORE_FILE'`

**Running it locally on Android Studio terminal works but in pipeline it doesn't work.**

If the file path or location is the problem the error message should not `Could not get unknown property`.

Comment: In which file do you store DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE these variables's values?

Comment: @manmohan You can see it in `Create Keystores and Google Play API key file` step above

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS have you fixed?, I'm facing the same issue, my pipeline builds the apk then I verify the signatures between the apk generated by Android Studio and the one from the Pipeline, and the signatures don't match, btw I'm using the next command   keytool -printcert -jarfile app-debug.apk

Comment: @V1t0r14n0 you need to use the same keystore so that the signature and SHAs will be the same from your local and pipeline. To do this you will need to convert your keystore file to base64 then decode it and create an artifact file of it during build time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the spacing between

```
-PANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION

-PDEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE=../keys/$DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE
```

down to

```
-PBUILD_NUMBER=$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER

clean :app:publishReleaseBundle
```

there should be no space there as you pointed out that `-PANDROID_BUILD_COMPILED_SDK_VERSION` is working. Putting new line spaces makes the command incomplete.

It will fix your current issue, **BUT** you will encounter another problem as your environment variable does not match from the command task and Bitbucket repository variable page. Change your variable name either on command or website.

In BB page you have no variable named `DEBUG_KEY_PASSWORD`.

Double check the other variables and properties in both command task and Bitbucket repository variable you may also missed another one.

Comment: Yes! This is the correct one, those bloody spaces and thanks for checking the variables as well as I discover another mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the Bamboo variables in your specs with `bamboo_` as per https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-variables-289277087.html. For example `$DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE` becomes `$bamboo_DEBUG_KEYSTORE_FILE`.